# How can I make my CSS aligns elements in the center of the screen properly?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

1. I am experiencing an issue with my div element where I have attempted to center it, but it does not align with the center of the screen as intended.

   [Image Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPrXz.png)

Html

```
 <div class="right_col">
    <nav>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Posts</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>About</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Membership</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Merch</li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>Reviews</li>
        </ul>

        <button class="join"><i class="ri-user-add-fill"></i> Join Organization</button>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header_wrapper .cols_container .right_col nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column; 
}

.header_wrapper .cols_container .right_col nav ul{
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-direction: column; 
    align-items: center;

}

.header_wrapper .cols_container .right_col nav ul li{ 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #808080;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.header_wrapper .cols_container .right_col nav ul li a{ 
    text-decoration: none;
}


.header_wrapper .cols_container .right_col nav button{
    background: #730000;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Could there be any instances where conflicting CSS rules or styles, such as overlapping or contradictory positioning properties, are present and influencing the intended centering of the div element?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: why don't you try to add padding:0; for your li